# Not able to find elements in side a iframe using xpath

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe

I am trying to print all anchor tags inside a iframe on a website https://www.toolsqa.com/iframe-practice-page/ but webdriver is returning 0 elements

i have moved control from the main window to the iframe using swithcTo method but its not helpful

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='IF2']")));

@Test
public void iFrmesCount(String browserName) throws InterruptedException {
    if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers//chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();}
    driver.get("https://www.toolsqa.com/iframe-practice-page/ ");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='IF2']")));
    System.out.println("Span's inside iframe" + driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//span")).size());
    System.out.println("Div's inside iframe" + driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div")).size());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    driver.get("https://www.toolsqa.com/iframe-practice-page/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.switchTo().frame("IF2");
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());
    }
```

Comment: When i use WebElement of iframe  as argument for driver.switchTo().frame(-), didn't work. But, when i use ID as the argument, it worked, why so?

Comment: Try to make screenshot of a page with selenium to figure things out. WebElement option works with another window dimensions - if you make `driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920,1080));` instead of `driver.manage().window().maximize();`.